# R - Knit HTML output in wrong directory

Tags: r, terminal, directory

When I knit my .Rmd file to HTML, instead of saving the output to the same directory as the .Rmd file, RStudio saves the .html file and a copy of the original .Rmd file to my home directory instead of my working directory. Any idea how to fix this? Purely for organization purposes I'd like the output to be in the same directory as the oringinal .Rmd file.

Comment: You could  maybe use `render("x.Rmd",output_file = "y.pdf", output_dir = getwd())`?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Dean Aatali's [**ezknitr**](https://github.com/ropensci/ezknitr) package, which he wrote to correct this and a few other infelicities of **knitr**'s input and output directory defaults. `ezknitr::ezknit()` "just works" as you'd like it to, writing its outputted HTML file to the directory contain the markdown file, instead of (as `knitr::knit()` would) to the current working directory:

```
## Reproducible e.g.
dir.create("path/to", recursive=TRUE)
cat("Hello world", "path/to/eg.Rmd")

## Check how it works
ezknitr::ezknit("path/to/eg.Rmd")
dir("path/to/")
[1] "eg.html" "eg.md"  "eg.Rmd"
```